# How to set 2 images to be by the side of each other

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have made use of a canvas to create a gauge and it is displaying perfectly on the web browser. However, I am planning to display 2 gauges that are side by side of each other; one gauge is to reflect on the speed of the user interaction, the other gauge is to serve as a purpose of the counter. Furthermore, the gauge will be activated upon the initial user interaction on the start button.

***Issue:***

At this point in time, I have managed to create and correctly display the first gauge. Hence, to create 2 canvas images, I have created 2 `<canvas>` tags, and when I created the second `<script>` tag for the second  `<canvas>`, the 2nd canvas image is superimposed on the 1st `<canvas>` tag. Therefore, I wouldn't be able to see the 1st canvas image.

Hence, I would like to ask for help on how to enable the 2 canvas image to be by the side of each other?

***Code:***
I have removed the `<script>` code for the creation of the 2nd canvas, it might not have been correct to begin with, hence i have removed it.

***HTML***

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
 </canvas>
 <canvas id="Counter" width="300" height="300">
 </canvas>
```

***CSS***

```
 #canvas {
           display: block;
           width: 300px;
           margin: 100px auto;
 }
 /*Custom font for numbers*/
 @font-face {
           font-family: "bebas";
 }
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
window.onload = function(){
           //canvas initialization
           var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
           var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
           //dimensions
           var W = canvas.width;
           var H = canvas.height;
           //Variables
           var degrees = 0;
           var new_degrees = 0;
           var difference = 0;
           var color = "#ffa500"; //green looks better to me
           var bgcolor = "#654321";
           var text;
           var animation_loop, redraw_loop;

           function init()
           {
              //Clear the canvas everytime a chart is drawn
              ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

              //Background 360 degree arc
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.strokeStyle = bgcolor;
              ctx.lineWidth = 30;
              ctx.arc(W/2, H/2, 100, 0, Math.PI*2, false); //you can see the arc now
              ctx.stroke();

              //gauge will be a simple arc
              //Angle in radians = angle in degrees * PI / 180
              var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.lineWidth = 30;
              //The arc starts from the rightmost end. If we deduct 90 degrees from the angles
              //the arc will start from the topmost end
              ctx.arc(W/2, H/2, 100, 0 - 90*Math.PI/180, radians - 90*Math.PI/180, false); 
              //you can see the arc now
              ctx.stroke();

              //Lets add the text
              ctx.fillStyle = color;
              ctx.font = "50px bebas";
              text = Math.floor(degrees/360*100) + "ms";
              //Lets center the text deducting half of text width from position x
              text_width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
              //adding manual value to position y since the height of the text cannot be measured easily. There are hacks but we will keep it manual for now.
              ctx.fillText(text, W/2 - text_width/2, H/2 + 15);
               }

           function draw()
           {
              //Cancel any movement animation if a new chart is requested
              if(typeof animation_loop != undefined) clearInterval(animation_loop);

              //random degree from 0 to 360
              new_degrees = Math.round(Math.random()*360);
              difference = new_degrees - degrees;
              animation_loop = setInterval(animate_to, 1000/difference);
           }

           //function to make the chart move to new degrees
           function animate_to()
           {
              //clear animation loop if degrees reaches to new_degrees
              if(degrees == new_degrees) 
              clearInterval(animation_loop);

              if(degrees < new_degrees)degrees++;
              else
                  degrees--;

              init();
           }

           //Lets add some animation for fun
           draw();
            //Draw a new chart every 2 seconds
           redraw_loop = setInterval(draw, 2000); 
        }
```

Comment: Why not use 1 wider canvas? When either of the 2 gauges needs to be updated you just erase that half of the canvas and redraw that guage. :-)

Comment: @markE could you please demonstrate how that could be done? THanks a lot

Comment: Sure. Your refactoring is remarkably simple--you don't even have to change your gauge drawing code! :-) First, widen the canvas: `<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300">`. Then to draw the righthand gauge you (1) Shift the drawing surface rightward with `ctx.translate(300,0)`, (2) Draw your gauge using your existing code, (3) Unshift the drawing surfact with `ctx.translate(-300,0)`. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given your second canvas any styles.

Make them both `inline-block`, they will be next to eachother.

http://jsbin.com/vabevadoto/edit?html,css,js,output

I added a red outline so you could see the second canvas container is indeed there and next to the other once you make them inline-blocks.

```
 #canvas {
           display: inline-block;
           width: 300px;
           margin: 100px auto;
 }

#Counter {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I do see the red box that is beside the initial gauge. Will work my way around so that it will call the second image as well!

Comment: great! The gauge looks very nice btw.

Comment: Thank you!!managed to get it!!Thanks a lot for your help. Do you mind if you could help me upvote too?

Comment: @Luke you're welcome, glad to help. :-) I'm not sure what you mean, are you asking how to mark an answer correct on Stack Overflow? Seems you got it (thanks!)

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job for you

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="float:left; display:block;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="Counter" width="300" height="300" style="float:left; display:block;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: There seems to be no link?

Comment: That was very strange. First Brien12 quickly gets the first answer in with a little text but no actual answer. Then Manoj Kumar edits the post a minute later and adds code to it. If this is some kind of crazy rep farming scheme I don't understand it.

Comment: I figured it out by viewing the edit history. The code was there in the original answer, but because it wasn't formatted as code it wasn't appearing. The edit was just to format it as code so it would be visible.